# Create Thread that wait until var change

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, thread-safety

I want to have a single thread, that consuming from a queue and multiple threads, producing work and placing it on this queue - and then allowing the original producing threads be able to wait (at some point) for that work to have been done and continue working with the object.

somthing like this:

```
loop:
1. TheThread waiting for "myObj pending" is not null.
2. Thread2 changing "pending" object.
3.1. TheThread do some stuff on "pending"
3.2. Thread2 doing some another stuff.
4. Thread2 waiting until Thread finished, and then do something on "pending" and return him to be null
[there is many "Thread"s like "Thread2", and I want it to be ThreadSafe]
```

I tryied to do it in the code below, but this is my first time using Threads, so I don't realy sure what am I doing wrong, and if there is an efficient way.

```
ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
myObj pending = null;

Thread worker = new Thread(doWork);
Thread.start();
Thread Thread2 = new Thread(anotherMethod);
Thread Thread3 = new Thread(anotherMethod2); 

void doWork()
{
while (true)
    {            
        if (pending == null)
            {
                mre.waitOne()
            }
        lock(pending)
        {
            pending.doSomething();
            mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        }
    }
}

void anotherMethod()
{
    //doStuff
    pending = new myObj()
    mre.set();
    //doStuff
    worker.Join()
    pending.doSomeThingJustIfDoWorkDone()        
}

void anotherMethod2()
{
    //doStuff
    pending = new myObj()
    mre.set();
    //doStuff
    worker.Join()
    pending.doSomeThingJustIfDoWorkDone()        
}
```

Comment: It looks (somewhat) like what you're attempting to do is to have a single thread consuming from a queue and multiple threads producing work and placing it on this queue - and then allowing the original producing thread(s) be able to wait (at some point) for that work to have been done and continue working with the object. Is that a fair description?

Comment: Exactly. I'll use your explanation in the question. 
do you know how to solve it? @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Classic method: pass a synchro object in the task object and have the task code signal it when it has done its work.  The originating thread can wait on the synchro after enqueueing the task.

Comment: Classic II: inherit the task from a class that has a virtual 'OnCompletion' method that the task/threadpool always calls.  Eitehr make it abstract, forcing the user to override, or have an empty base method that does nothing so the user can override if required.  Such an override could signal a synchro object that the originator will wait on.

Comment: Classic III - pass a delegate that the task/threadpool calls on completion if it is not null.  The delegate can signal a synchro object that the originator will wait on.

Comment: Worst possible design - some gruesome Join() thingy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` in 4.5 that does exactly what you want.

In general, your use case is described in Richter's book "CLR via C#" and is called `Condition In variable pattern`.

```
internal sealed class ConditionVariablePattern {
  private readonly Object m_lock = new Object();
  private Boolean m_condition = false;
  public void Thread1() {
    Monitor.Enter(m_lock); // Acquire a mutual-exclusive lock
    // While under the lock, test the complex condition "atomically"
    while (!m_condition) {
    // If condition is not met, wait for another thread to change the condition
       Monitor.Wait(m_lock); // Temporarily release lock so other threads can get it
    }
    // The condition was met, process the data...
    Monitor.Exit(m_lock); // Permanently release lock
 }
 public void Thread2() {
    Monitor.Enter(m_lock); // Acquire a mutual-exclusive lock
   // Process data and modify the condition...
   m_condition = true;
   // Monitor.Pulse(m_lock); // Wakes one waiter AFTER lock is released
   Monitor.PulseAll(m_lock); // Wakes all waiters AFTER lock is released
   Monitor.Exit(m_lock); // Release lock
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When working with threads I prefer to use Tasks to manage them.

I think that the method ContinueWith in the Task Parallel Library, is the one you are looking for. Take a look at this examples, maybe this could help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537612.aspx

Comment: That would be sufficient if TS needs such scheduler that would be limited to creating publisher threads(that creates object) and immediately schedule consumer after it via ContinueWith(). Otherwise, how can one knows when to schedule consumer - when to write ContinueWith and when not to write.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`worker.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to wait until your worker thread completes. You can join multiple threads.

I think you'd be better off using [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of manually handling threads.

Comment: This is not my problem.. my problem is how to make it Thread safe.. I edit the question to be more specific. @zmbq

Comment: there is many Threads that call doWork by changing "pending", I want any Thread that "want" to use "doWork" will wait untill "pending" be null (meaning: doWork is free and waiting) @zmbq

Answer (score 0):

you should lock  another object because what you are doing may lead to a deadlock 
 instead of the pending object  it will be better  to make something  like  something like

```
private readonly Object  _myPendingLock = new Object();
```

and you should lock this object whenever you call pending object

```
 void anotherMethod()
{
 lock(_myPendingLock)
    //doStuff
    pending = new myObj()
    mew.set();
    //doStuff
    [...]
    worker.Join()
    pending.doSomeThingJustIfDoWorkDone()
 }
}
```

// but if you want the producer consumer in safest maner it will be better to take a look  at the built-in class

[[ConcurrentQueue Class]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi, thanks. But if I lock in "anotherMethod()", how "doWork()" use "pending" too? @Julie Shannon

Comment: it will wait until the lock is released AFAIK is the only way to make your code thread safe